# save base64 string in mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Should I save BASE64 strings in MYSQL?, given the following conditions:

1. The maximum size of the string will be 500KB, but on average it will be around 250KB.
2. Every day I have to keep between 400-1200 records.

Comment: Is your question whether this is a good idea? What alternatives have you considered?

Answer (score 0):

According to your specs your want to store between 100MB (=250KB*400) en 300MB (=1200*250KB) per day.

You can extrapolate that to month, which becomes a storage of between 3GB and 9GB (factor 30), or extrapolate to a year which becomes between 36.6 and 109.8 GB (factor 366).

All of this is without the space needed for indexes.

P.S. Yes, i do know a not is not 30 days, and a year is not 366 days, but that is not part of this question.